# Writing A Function for Tooltips in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force directed graph and I'm trying to write a function to display the names of the inbound and outbound nodes in a tooltip. I'm okay with the tooltip part, but I'm new to js and can't seem to get the function right. Here's what I'm trying:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
   names = ""
links.forEach (function(links)
  { if (links.source == d.name) {names.append (links.source)}}
  { if (links.target == d.name) {names.append (links.target)}}
  {return names}
  )});
```

I want to return the names string as html. I have to pass through the source and target because some nodes are only targets.

Comment: Can you check your code again. The code you posted here is not syntactically correct. Check your curly brackets.

Comment: What is the expected tool-tip for a node 'Item 1' which is connected to 'Item 2' in the same direction? It is not clear in your question. Do you want something like 'Item 1 -> Item 2'?

Comment: I'm hoping to display every node that's connected on a new line (regardless of direction) by inserting breaks between each "neighbor" that gets appended to the empty string